# Show Yes/No instead of 0/1 in datagrid view for c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview, boolean

I'm filling a datagrid in c# from a SQLite database, but SQLite databases have no true boolean value, so I've made an SQLite INTEGER field with a check to ensure it is 0 or 1.  Instead of show that 0 or 1 in the datagrid, I'd like to show a Yes/no.  1=Yes, 0=No.  I'd like the data in the DB to stay the same, just change what is displayed to the user.  The sql statement filling the table right now is a simple one:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

EDIT:
The field in question is the "Injured" field.
Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "SmashRoster" (
    "SmashRosterID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "CharacterName" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "TotalTournaments"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Wins"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Losses"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Championships" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "InjuriesCaused"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Injured"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK(Injured IN (0,1))
);
```

Method used to pull the data from the DB, Bind to the datagrid is at the bottom:

```
  SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data 
    Source=C:\SQLiteDB\SQLiteDB.db;Version=3;");
  SQLiteCommand cmd;
  SQLiteDataReader dataReader;
  DataTable roster;

  cnn.Open();
  cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"SELECT * FROM SmashRoster", cnn);
  roster = new DataTable();

  dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  roster.Load(dataReader);

  dataReader.Close();
  cmd.Dispose();
  cnn.Dispose();
  rosterGridView.DataSource = roster;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data value is an integer as you say, you can use the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView` control like this:

```
private void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, ataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if ( e.ColumnIndex == columnIndex )
    if ( e.Value is int )
      e.Value = (int)e.Value == 0 ? "No" : "Yes";
}
```

All values other than 0 are considered true else you can modify the test as you want.

Replace `columnIndex` by the index you need starting from 0.

Also replace the `int` check and cast by `long` if you use a SQLite x64 driver.

You can also use the column name like this:

```
if ( (sender as DataGridView)?.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "column name" )
```

Or the binded data property name from your query:

```
if ( (sender as DataGridView)?.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "name" )
```

Using column index or name you are independant from the query.

Using data property name you are independant from the columns order and naming.

You may choose what you prefer.

Comment: Since it's my 8th column, I just put in the no. 8 right? This didn't throw any exceptions, but also had no effect on the view.

Comment: The eighth column has index of 7 (the collection starts from 0).

Comment: Ah, once the i tried index 7 i got an invalid cast, as with the other answers.  It seems like the SQLite INTEGER data type may not be the same as the int used in the code?

Comment: It is strange because the SQLite INTEGER is an int in C#. I use it on typed DataSet without problem. Can you add some code in your question: table schema and how do you got the data and how do you bind the grid.

Comment: I have added those details and code segments into the question.

Comment: Thanks. You may prefer typed DataSet. Can you do this test instead of the `e.Value = ...` : `{ MessageBox.Show((sender as DataGridView)?.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName); MessageBox.Show(e.Value.GetType().Name); }`, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201833/discussion-between-christian-caraballo-and-olivier-rogier).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was scratching my head on this one for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the situation.

You could use a case expression directly in the sql statement. See https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-case/

If you use some business object layer, you could have a specific property to expose this field as a calculated string instead of a integer. With ADO.NET Dataset/Datatable, you could have the same behaviour with Expression column https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns

You could use the CellFormatting event of the datagridview to spot the right column and convert the Int to a String.